# Render staggering images in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say for example, I have a list of elements that I want to render in a staggered fashion:

```
let items = [
{title: 'title 1', source: 'img/src/1'},
{title: 'title 2', source: 'img/src/2'},
{title: 'title 3', source: 'img/src/3'}
]
```

Desired output after render():

```
title 1 [img 1]
[img 2] title 2
title 3 [img 3]
```

How can I accomplish this? I guess what I'm asking is, how do I iterate through my list items, and return different markup based on their index?

```
items.map(function(item, i) {
   return //Need help here
})
```

Comment: How about doing the staggering via CSS ?`tr:nth-child(even) {float:left}
tr:nth-child(odd) {float:right}`

Comment: I like the idea of that. Less code probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `i` index to determine when it is Odd and when it is Even. Depending on that render different UI `React` element

```
items.map(function(item, i) {
   if (i % 2) {
      // i is odd number
      // render one type of UI element
   } else {
     // i is even number
     // render another UI element
   }
});
```

So in `React` parent component you can write something like this:

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return {
      <div>
        {items.map((item, index) =>
          index % 2 ?
          <UIElement1 />
          :
          <UIElement2 />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or if you have the same UI element but its styling or logic would changed based on if it is odd or even

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return {
      <div>
        {items.map((item, index) =>
          <UIElement
            isOdd={!!(index % 2)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or if you have the same UI element but its class changes based on if element is odd or even

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return {
      <div>
        {items.map((item, index) =>
          <UIElement
            className={index % 2 ? className1 : className2}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for. Opted to go with the if-then-else syntax since it's more react-ive